# Excel Users only able to Fill Cell from Select Colors

Tags: excel, colors, limit, fill

I'm trying to make it so that select cells within a group of data, can only be filled with 1 of 4 pre-selected colors.  Kind of like a drop-down menu list but for fill colors instead.

We have a team of about 9 working within an excel file at the same time.  Time is of the essence, and some of our communication and input to each other is with the color of fill for select data.

Since there are many colors available, we can get a strange mix of shades, hindering our production.

Is there a way to limit the fill colors to just a pre-selected group?

I've only researched Data Validation drop-down menus as that is the only thing my limited knowledge could think of.

With the ride range of data variables and form, have not found a way where Conditional Formatting would be possible.  With our process, the data can remain the same but we communicate with colors on whether or not the data is valid and ready to go.  The user needs to be able to change the cell color arbituarily.

Unfortunately I haven't come close to what I've been looking for.

Comment: "With the ride range of data variables and form, have not found a way where Conditional Formatting would be possible" Maybe provide some examples and one of your attempts and a solution could be found?

Comment: You can still use conditional formatting, but have 4 helper columns where the user puts an `x` in the column of the color wanted and conditional formatting formats the correct cell with the correct color based on which column has the `x`.  There is no way outside to do this without helper columns.  Another is to have the drop down with the word of the color in a helper column then use that column again as the criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim StrColorbox01Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox02Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox03Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox04Name As String
    Dim StrActivatorName As String
    Dim ObjColorbox01 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox02 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox03 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox04 As Object
    Dim ObjActivator As Object
    Dim DblSize As Double
    
    
    StrColorbox01Name = "ObjCB01"
    StrColorbox02Name = "ObjCB02"
    StrColorbox03Name = "ObjCB03"
    StrColorbox04Name = "ObjCB04"
    
    StrActivatorName = "ObjActivator"
    
    DblSize = 15
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjColorbox01 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox01Name)
    Set ObjColorbox02 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox02Name)
    Set ObjColorbox03 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox03Name)
    Set ObjColorbox04 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox04Name)
    
    Set ObjActivator = Me.Shapes(StrActivatorName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ObjColorbox01 Is Nothing Or ObjColorbox02 Is Nothing Or ObjColorbox03 Is Nothing Or ObjColorbox04 Is Nothing Or ObjActivator Is Nothing Then
        
        On Error Resume Next
        ObjColorbox01.Delete
        ObjColorbox02.Delete
        ObjColorbox03.Delete
        ObjColorbox04.Delete
        ObjActivator.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        With Me.Shapes
            
            Set ObjColorbox01 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, DblSize, DblSize)
            Set ObjColorbox02 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ObjColorbox01.Left + ObjColorbox01.Width, ObjColorbox01.Top, ObjColorbox01.Width, ObjColorbox01.Height)
            Set ObjColorbox03 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ObjColorbox02.Left + ObjColorbox02.Width, ObjColorbox02.Top, ObjColorbox02.Width, ObjColorbox02.Height)
            Set ObjColorbox04 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ObjColorbox03.Left + ObjColorbox03.Width, ObjColorbox03.Top, ObjColorbox03.Width, ObjColorbox03.Height)
            Set ObjActivator = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ObjColorbox04.Left + ObjColorbox04.Width, ObjColorbox04.Top, ObjColorbox04.Width, ObjColorbox04.Height)
            
            ObjColorbox01.Name = StrColorbox01Name
            ObjColorbox02.Name = StrColorbox02Name
            ObjColorbox03.Name = StrColorbox03Name
            ObjColorbox04.Name = StrColorbox04Name
            ObjActivator.Name = StrActivatorName
            
            ObjColorbox01.DrawingObject.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ObjColorbox02.DrawingObject.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ObjColorbox03.DrawingObject.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            ObjColorbox04.DrawingObject.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ObjActivator.DrawingObject.Interior.Color = RGB(127, 127, 127)
            
            ObjColorbox01.OnAction = "SubColor01"
            ObjColorbox02.OnAction = "SubColor02"
            ObjColorbox03.OnAction = "SubColor03"
            ObjColorbox04.OnAction = "SubColor04"
            
            ObjActivator.OnAction = "SubColorPaletteOnOff"
            
            ObjActivator.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON"
            
            With ObjActivator.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange.TextFrame2
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorNone
                .MarginLeft = 0
                .MarginRight = 0
                .MarginTop = 0
                .MarginBottom = 0
                .WordWrap = msoFalse
                .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
            End With
            
        End With
        
    Else
        
        Set ObjColorbox02 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox02Name)
        Set ObjColorbox03 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox03Name)
        Set ObjColorbox04 = Me.Shapes(StrColorbox04Name)
        
        ObjColorbox01.Height = DblSize
        ObjColorbox01.Width = DblSize
        
        ObjColorbox02.Height = ObjColorbox01.Height
        ObjColorbox02.Width = ObjColorbox01.Width
        ObjColorbox03.Height = ObjColorbox01.Height
        ObjColorbox03.Width = ObjColorbox01.Width
        ObjColorbox04.Height = ObjColorbox01.Height
        ObjColorbox04.Width = ObjColorbox01.Width
        
    End If
    
    
    If ObjActivator.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON" Then
        
        ObjColorbox01.Top = Target.Cells(1, 1).Top + Target.Cells(1, 1).Height
        ObjColorbox01.Left = Target.Cells(1, 1).Left + Target.Cells(1, 1).Width
        
        ObjColorbox02.Top = ObjColorbox01.Top
        ObjColorbox02.Left = ObjColorbox01.Left + ObjColorbox01.Width
        ObjColorbox03.Top = ObjColorbox02.Top
        ObjColorbox03.Left = ObjColorbox02.Left + ObjColorbox02.Width
        ObjColorbox04.Top = ObjColorbox03.Top
        ObjColorbox04.Left = ObjColorbox03.Left + ObjColorbox03.Width
        ObjActivator.Top = ObjColorbox04.Top
        ObjActivator.Left = ObjColorbox04.Left + ObjColorbox04.Width
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Put this in a public module:

```
Sub SubColor01()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjActivator").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON" Then
        
        Selection.Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjCB01").DrawingObject.Interior.Color
        
    End If
    
End Sub
Sub SubColor02()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjActivator").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON" Then
        
        Selection.Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjCB02").DrawingObject.Interior.Color
        
    End If
    
End Sub
Sub SubColor03()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjActivator").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON" Then
        
        Selection.Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjCB03").DrawingObject.Interior.Color
        
    End If
    
End Sub
Sub SubColor04()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjActivator").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ON" Then
        
        Selection.Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ObjCB04").DrawingObject.Interior.Color
        
    End If
    
End Sub
Sub SubColorPaletteOnOff()
    
    Dim StrColorbox01Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox02Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox03Name As String
    Dim StrColorbox04Name As String
    Dim StrActivatorName As String
    Dim ObjColorbox01 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox02 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox03 As Object
    Dim ObjColorbox04 As Object
    Dim ObjActivator As Object
    Dim RngRestingRange As Range
    
    StrColorbox01Name = "ObjCB01"
    StrColorbox02Name = "ObjCB02"
    StrColorbox03Name = "ObjCB03"
    StrColorbox04Name = "ObjCB04"
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set ObjActivator = .Shapes("ObjActivator")
        Set ObjColorbox01 = .Shapes(StrColorbox01Name)
        Set ObjColorbox02 = .Shapes(StrColorbox02Name)
        Set ObjColorbox03 = .Shapes(StrColorbox03Name)
        Set ObjColorbox04 = .Shapes(StrColorbox04Name)
        Set RngRestingRange = .Range("A1")
    End With
        
    With ObjActivator.OLEFormat.Object
    
        Select Case .Caption
            Case Is = "ON"
                .Caption = "OFF"
                
                ObjColorbox01.Top = RngRestingRange.Cells(1, 1).Top
                ObjColorbox01.Left = RngRestingRange.Cells(1, 1).Left
                
                ObjColorbox02.Top = ObjColorbox01.Top
                ObjColorbox02.Left = ObjColorbox01.Left + ObjColorbox01.Width
                ObjColorbox03.Top = ObjColorbox02.Top
                ObjColorbox03.Left = ObjColorbox02.Left + ObjColorbox02.Width
                ObjColorbox04.Top = ObjColorbox03.Top
                ObjColorbox04.Left = ObjColorbox03.Left + ObjColorbox03.Width
                ObjActivator.Top = ObjColorbox04.Top
                ObjActivator.Left = ObjColorbox04.Left + ObjColorbox04.Width
                
            Case Is = "OFF"
                .Caption = "ON"
            Case Else
                .Caption = "OFF"
        End Select
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Main advantage: you can select multiple ranges as you like and change their fillings just with the clicks you need to select the wanted ranges plus one for the color.

Answer (score 1):

Use data validation on a column with the color as a word, then use conditional formatting to set the color.

[image]

[image]